# Auto resize ScrollPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to resize ScrollPane to fit the parent component. I tested this code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
        bp.setPrefSize(600, 600);
        bp.setMaxSize(600, 600);
        bp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #2f4f4f;");

        VBox vb = new VBox(bp);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(vb);
        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);

        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

But as you can see I don't see tree scroll bars. Is there anything wrong into my code?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scrollbars won't show up because

1. You have the policy set to `ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED`
2. The width and height of the scroll bars are automatically resized to that of its' container, which, in this case, is your resizable Vbox.

To fix this, you could remove `setFitToHeight` and `setFitToWidth` and leave them as false.

Note that `ScrollBarPolicy` could also be set to `ALWAYS` as opposed to `AS_NEEDED`, which will keep the scroll bars even when the window is expanded.

[Refer here for more information using ScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/scrollpane.htm)

[ScrollPane API: setFitToHeight](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#setFitToHeight(boolean))

```
    public class MainApp extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

            BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();
            bp.setPrefSize(600, 600);
            bp.setMaxSize(600, 600);
            bp.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #2f4f4f;");

            VBox vb = new VBox(bp);

            ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(vb);
            //scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
            //scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

            scrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
            scrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);

            Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane);

            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }
```